# Assigning a void pointer from function works in one source file, but not in two

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, casting

So I'm working through [this chapter of a sweet modern OpenGL tutorial](http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Chapter-2.1%3a-Buffers-and-Textures.html), and in part of the code I assign a void pointer variable to the return value of a `void *` function from a second file. I got this error from gcc: `initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast`. As a test, I tried merging the two files and compiling again. This time, with the function in the same file as where it's called, I get no error.

I was able to reproduce this with three minimal files:

**file1.c**

```
void main() {
    void *newval = foo();
}
```

**file2.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void *foo() {
    void *val;
    val = malloc(10);
    return val;
}
```

**file3.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void *foo() {
    void *val;
    val = malloc(10);
    return val;
}

void main() {
    void *newval = foo();
}
```

file3.c is just the first two combined. My question is why when I compile one way I get an error, and the other way I get none:

> $gcc file1.c file2.c
> file1.c: In function ‘main’: file1.c:2:17:
>   warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
>   [enabled by default]
> $gcc file3.c
> $

I thought that the file1.c + file2.c combo was identical to file3.c. What am I missing?

Comment: It's generally recommended to compile using `-Wall` with gcc to get additional warnings about missing prototypes, etc.  You should treat all warnings as errors, and search StackOverflow for reasons for the warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `file1.c`, it seems the declaration of `void *foo()` is missing.
You can either include the header file containing this declaration or add line `void *foo()` on top of `file1.c`.

When compiler finds symbol `foo` followed by `(` in main file, and there was no declaration, it assumes `foo` accepts any number of arguments and returns an int. So you see the warning that `int` is being converted to a pointer.

But in file `file3.c`, symbol `foo` is known as it is a defined function before its first usage so compiler knows that `foo` returns a pointer and thus no warning.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the `foo()` function so that compiler knows what it is when it compiles `file1.c`.

Create file2.h and add in it

```
void *foo();
```

add include it in file.c

```
#include "file2.h"
```

Without declaration, the compiler assumes all unknown functions as returning `int`, but as your function returns `void *` and you are assigning it to `void *`, its trying to assign `int` to `void *` and hence you are getting that warning.